# Scrape web untill the "next" page is disabled

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

```
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ie/Attraction_Review-g295424-d2038312-Reviews-Global_Village-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
def get_links():
  review_links = []
  for review_link in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'title'},href=True):
      review_link = review_link['href']
      review_links.append(review_link)
  return review_links
link = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ie'
review_urls = []
for i in get_links():
   review_url = link + i
   print (review_url)
review_urls.append(review_url)
```

Here this code to save all the hyperlinks present on this webpage - but I want to scrape all the hyperlinks on the pages till 319. Not able to implement when pagination is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a param you can change in the url to loop and get all the reviews.
So I just added a loop  and requests all the urls

```
def get_page(index):
    url = "https://www.tripadvisor.ie/Attraction_Review-g295424-d2038312-Reviews-or{}-Global_Village-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html".format(str(index))
    html = requests.get(url)
    page = soup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    return page

nb_review = 3187
for i in range(0, nb_review, 10):
    page = get_page(i)
```

The full code using your snippet is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

def get_page(index):
    url = "https://www.tripadvisor.ie/Attraction_Review-g295424-d2038312-Reviews-or{}-Global_Village-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html".format(str(index))
    html = requests.get(url)
    page = soup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    return page

def get_links(page):
  review_links = []
  for review_link in page.find_all('a', {'class':'title'},href=True):
      review_link = review_link['href']
      review_links.append(review_link)
  return review_links

link = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ie'
review_urls = []
nb_review = 3187
for i in range(0, nb_review, 10):
    page = get_page(i)
    for i in get_links(page):
        review_url = link + i
        review_urls.append(review_url)
print(len(review_urls))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
3187
```

**EDIT:**

You can obviously scrape the first page and get the review number to upgrade the code to make it more customizable